# DMN neural network with poor validation results -- only 50%

Tags: python-3.x, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

I have this problem with my Neural Network. I'm trying to implement what's called a DMN (Dynamic Memory Network) for the babi data set. A paper about the DMN model can be found here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07285 Another paper about DMNs can be found here: https://yerevann.github.io/2016/02/05/implementing-dynamic-memory-networks/

Here's my problem. btw I'm using PyTorch.

I split the training and testing data into parts for training, testing, and validation. I use 1000 parts for training, 500 parts for testing and 500 parts for validation. I run into a problem. I can train successfully but when I go to the validation step I never get a score above 50% accuracy. With the babi data set it is documented that you should be able to get 100% accuracy with the first test set. (There are 20 test sets in all). I can get 100% accuracy during training, but only 50% in validation. My question to you is what part of the program would be responsible for this kind of behavior? In other words, can you tell me why I'm always getting 50% ?? Thanks for your time. I'm limiting my experiments to the first babi test for now.

I thought I had this all figured out but my problem has cropped up again. I really don't have a clue what it is. Here is a link to the code. If you could take a look I would be most grateful. https://github.com/radiodee1/awesome-chatbot/blob/master/model/babi_iv.py

Some code is included below.

```
class WrapMemRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,vocab_size, embed_dim,  hidden_size, n_layers, dropout=0.3, do_babi=True, bad_token_lst=[], freeze_embedding=False, embedding=None, print_to_screen=False):
        super(WrapMemRNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.do_babi = do_babi
        self.print_to_screen = print_to_screen
        self.bad_token_lst = bad_token_lst
        self.embedding = embedding
        self.freeze_embedding = freeze_embedding
        self.teacher_forcing_ratio = hparams['teacher_forcing_ratio']

        gru_dropout = dropout * 0

        self.model_1_enc = Encoder(vocab_size, embed_dim, hidden_size, n_layers, dropout=dropout,embedding=embedding, bidirectional=False)
        self.model_2_enc = Encoder(vocab_size, embed_dim, hidden_size, n_layers, dropout=gru_dropout, embedding=embedding, bidirectional=False)
        self.model_3_mem_a = MemRNN(hidden_size, dropout=gru_dropout)
        self.model_3_mem_b = MemRNN(hidden_size, dropout=gru_dropout)
        self.model_4_att = EpisodicAttn(hidden_size, dropout=gru_dropout)
        self.model_5_ans = AnswerModule(vocab_size, hidden_size,dropout=dropout)

        self.input_var = None  # for input
        self.q_var = None  # for question
        self.answer_var = None  # for answer
        self.q_q = None  # extra question
        self.inp_c = None  # extra input
        self.inp_c_seq = None
        self.all_mem = None
        self.last_mem = None  # output of mem unit
        self.prediction = None  # final single word prediction
        self.memory_hops = hparams['babi_memory_hops']

        self.reset_parameters()

        if self.freeze_embedding or self.embedding is not None:
            self.new_freeze_embedding()
        #self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

        pass

    def reset_parameters(self):
        #print('reset')
        stdv = 1.0 / math.sqrt(self.hidden_size)
        for weight in self.parameters():
            #print('here...')
            weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
            if len(weight.size()) > 1:
                init.xavier_normal_(weight)

    def forward(self, input_variable, question_variable, target_variable, criterion=None):

        self.new_input_module(input_variable, question_variable)
        self.new_episodic_module()
        outputs,  ans = self.new_answer_module_simple()

        return outputs, None, ans, None

    def new_freeze_embedding(self):
        self.model_1_enc.embed.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.model_2_enc.embed.weight.requires_grad = False
        print('freeze embedding')
        pass

    def new_input_module(self, input_variable, question_variable):

        prev_h1 = []

        for ii in input_variable:

            ii = self.prune_tensor(ii, 2)

            out1, hidden1 = self.model_1_enc(ii, None)

            prev_h1.append(hidden1)

        self.inp_c_seq = prev_h1
        self.inp_c = prev_h1[-1]

        prev_h2 = []

        for ii in question_variable:
            ii = self.prune_tensor(ii, 2)

            out2, hidden2 = self.model_2_enc(ii, None)
            prev_h2.append(hidden2)

        self.q_q = hidden2[:,-1,:]

        return


    def new_episodic_module(self):
        if True:

            mem_list = []

            sequences = self.inp_c_seq

            for i in range(len(sequences)):

                m_list = [self.q_q.clone()]

                #print(sequences[i].size(),'seq')

                for iter in range(self.memory_hops):

                    x = self.new_attention_step(sequences[i], None, m_list[iter], self.q_q)

                    if self.print_to_screen and not self.training:
                        print(x,'x -- after', len(x), sequences[i].size())

                    e, _ = self.new_episode_small_step(sequences[i], x.permute(1,0), None)

                    assert len(sequences[i].size()) == 3
                    #print(e.size(),'e')
                    ee = e[:, 0, -1]#.permute(2,1,0)

                    _, out = self.model_3_mem_a(ee.unsqueeze(0), self.prune_tensor(m_list[iter], 3))

                    m_list.append(out)

                mem_list.append(m_list[self.memory_hops])

            mm_list = torch.cat(mem_list, dim=1)

            self.last_mem = mm_list

            #print(self.last_mem.size(),'lm')

        return None

    def new_episode_small_step(self, ct, g, prev_h):

        assert len(ct.size()) == 3
        bat, sen, emb = ct.size()
        #print(ct.size(),'ct')
        #print(sen,'sen', g.size())
        last = [prev_h]

        ep = []
        for iii in range(sen):

            c = ct[0,iii,:].unsqueeze(0)

            if prev_h is not None:
                prev_h = self.prune_tensor(prev_h, 3)

            out, gru = self.model_3_mem_b(c, last[iii] )

            last.append(out)

            g = g.squeeze(0)
            gru = gru.squeeze(0).permute(1,0)

            #if not self.training: print(g.size(),'g', iii)
            #ggg = g[:, iii]
            ggg = g[iii]
            h = torch.mul(ggg , gru)#  + torch.mul((1 - g[iii]) , prev_h.permute(1,0))

            index = -1 #-1 # -2
            if last[iii + index] is not None:
                #print(last[iii].size(),'last -',ggg.size(), ggg, sen)
                if False: h = h + torch.mul((1 - ggg), last[iii + index])

            #print(h.size(),'hsize')
            if iii == sen - 1 : ep.append(h.unsqueeze(1))

        h = torch.cat(ep, dim=1)

        #print(h.size(),ep[0].size(),'h',sen, gru.size())

        return h, gru

    def new_attention_step(self, ct, prev_g, mem, q_q):

        q_q = self.prune_tensor(q_q,3)
        mem = self.prune_tensor(mem,3)

        assert len(ct.size()) == 3
        bat, sen, emb = ct.size()

        #print(sen,'len sen')

        att = []
        for iii in range(sen):
            c = ct[0,iii,:]

            concat_list = [
                c.unsqueeze(0),
                mem.squeeze(0),
                q_q.squeeze(0),
                (c * q_q).squeeze(0),
                (c * mem).squeeze(0),
                (torch.abs(c - q_q) ).squeeze(0),
                (torch.abs(c - mem) ).squeeze(0)
            ]
            #for ii in concat_list: print(ii.size())
            #print(sen,'sen')
            #exit()
            #z = F.sigmoid(z)
            concat_list = torch.cat(concat_list, dim=1)
            #print(concat_list.size(),'cl')
            att.append(concat_list)

        att = torch.cat(att, dim=0)
        #z = torch.cat(att, dim=0)
        z = self.model_4_att(att)
        z = F.sigmoid(z)
        #z =  F.softmax(z, dim=1) #F.sigmoid(z)
        #print(z.size(),'z')
        return z

    def prune_tensor(self, input, size):
        if len(input.size()) < size:
            input = input.unsqueeze(0)
        if len(input.size()) > size:
            input = input.squeeze(0)
        return input

    def new_answer_module_simple(self):
        #outputs

        ansx = self.model_5_ans(self.last_mem, None)

        #ansx = F.softmax(ansx, dim=0)

        if self.print_to_screen:
            print(ansx, 'ansx printed')
            print(ansx.size(), 'ansx')
            vocab, sen = ansx.size()
            aa = torch.argmax(ansx, dim=0)
            print(aa.size(),'aa')
            for i in range(sen):
                zz = aa[i]
                z = ansx[:, i]
                a = torch.argmax(z, dim=0)
                print(a.item(), zz.item())
            print('----')
        #ans = torch.argmax(ansx,dim=1)#[0]


        return [None], ansx

        pass
```

Comment: To me, this sounds like you're overfitting and that hasn't necessarily got to do with your code. What happens if you take 1250 samples for training and 250 for validation? Also, change your dropout to 50% for maximum distribution. Or just train longer. There's a lot to do about this...

Comment: Validation is for adjusting the hyperparameters on your network and its data is only seen a couple of times during training. If you hit 50% on validation data but 100% on training, that means you're overfitting like crazy. You should do something about that. You are right about training longer indeed, don't know why I said that haha

Comment: I found this paper. It refers to DMN+, a more advanced Dynamic Memory Network, which can work with the babi data set. This is the link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01417 . They say in the paper that the input module on the basic DMN sometimes experiences overfitting. I followed the example as best as I could and my validation is much better.